# I, Michael William Holland, am the only direct decendant of T R King, my great grandfather. How do I go about claiming ownership of this patent?

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [US860486](https://www.google.com/patents/US860486)

Comment: This patent expired like a century ago. There's not much you can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: What are you planning to do if you could own this patent considering it expired 90 years ago?

Answer (score 3):

The term of a patent is (now) 20 years after the date of filing. Before 1995 the term of a patent was 17 years from the date of grant.

The patent you linkes was granted on 16 of July 1907. It probably expired 17 years later.

There is no way to claim this patent anymore because it does not protect anything anymore. A patent grants an exclusive right in return for the publication of an invention and free use for everyone after the expiry of that right, which is what happened here.

Comment: I guess there is the question of whether one can own an expired patent.

Comment: Does someone citing the patent extend it?

Comment: @MichaelWilliamHolland No, once a patent expires, it expires. This one has been expired for more than 90 years. There is no way to enforce it. To be absolutely clear, it has no monetary value whatsoever.

Comment: I suspected this was the case. Thanks! Peace!!!

Comment: @MichaelWilliamHolland if you found this answer acceptable (and I think it is) you should accept it by clicking the checkmark.